# Stop the insert values to mysql table when refresh the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a cash form in php called cash.php to enter payments.when i clicked submit button values store payments table in mysql successfully.but after clicking submit button and refreshing the page insert duplicate value of previous entry. php code and html code is in same page.i am new to php.please help me.my code is below.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row main">
        <div class="main-login main-center">
            <h2>Cash</h2>
            <br>
            <form class="" method="post" action="cash.php">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mno" id="mno"
                                   placeholder="Member Number"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"
                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mname" id="mname"
                                   placeholder="Member Name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nic" id="nic" placeholder="NIC"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money fa-lg"
                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa"
                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <select class="form-control" name="month" id="month">
                                <option selected disabled>Month</option>
                                <option value="January">January</option>
                                <option value="February">February</option>
                                <option value="March">March</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <label for="number" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Pay Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar fa"
                                                                  aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="paydate" id="paydate" type="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group " align="center">
                    <input style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);border: 2px solid #4CAF50;background-color: white;color: black;width: 50%;"
                           href="" target="_blank" type="submit" id="buttonpayment" name="buttonpayment1"
                           class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Submit"></input>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "doctor");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['buttonpayment1'])) {

    $number = $_POST["mno"];
    $name = $_POST["mname"];
    $nic = $_POST["nic"];
    $amount = $_POST["amount"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];
    $paydate = $_POST["paydate"];

    if ($number == "" || $name == "" || $nic == "" || $amount == "" || $month == "" || $paydate == "") {
        ?>
        <script>alert("There are some uncompleted fields.complete all fields to do the action")</script>
    <?php
    }
    else {


    $sql = "insert into payments (Mid,Mname,Mnic,amount,month,paydate,paymenttype) values('$number','$name','$nic','$amount','$month','$paydate','Cash')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    ?>
        <script>alert("Cash Payment is Successful2")</script>
    <?php


    } else {
    ?>
        <script>alert("Occured Error!!!! TRY AGAIN CASH PAYMENTS")</script>
        <?php
    }
    }
}
$conn->close();
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing ObjOriented and functional approach.

Comment: Just add redirect to the same page after you insert data to database

Comment: If you submit a form and then refresh the page, it will submit the form again with the same data. Most browsers will ask if you want to do that, and they will also repopulate the data when the page returns from the first submit. You might want to return (after the submit) to a confirmation page before showing the cash.php page.

Comment: nice sql injection there btw. if you want to keep your website/db intact, use a prepared statement.